# Switching HDMI input to Apple TV causes crackling noise and strange video

Tags: audio, video, appletv, hdmi

When I switch HDMI inputs on my TV from Tivo or Blu-ray to a sleeping Apple TV ([4th generation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apple_TV#4th_generation), with apps), I get nasty crackling electronic interference noise on the sound system plus weird LSD-acid-trip video display of the usual list of app icons (all the colors are wrong, reversed). I press Home or Menu buttons a couple times and after a long moment all is well and working.

Is this normal for an Apple TV? I've never had this crackling and crazy color video when switching inputs to the Tivo or Blu-ray, only the Apple TV.